# What mechanism would you use to lift, then at a certain point release something with a pulley, string & motor

Tags: motors, pulleys

I'd like to lift an inflatable cow up to a pulley I threw over a high branch and then release it to fall when it gets to the top, and then repeat the process. I currently have a loop of string between the pulley and a motor but the process to release and then re-engage is a mystery. It for a Halloween decoration so circuits and specialized gearing is definitely beyond me.

[image]

Comment: So have you checked those release mechanisms used by helicopters or those youtubers who drop things of high buildings / cliffs etc

Comment: Not yet, I'm thinking it's something that travels with the cow up the loop but when it hits the pulley one half detaches and falls back down. Not sure if they have that sort of requirement but I'll look.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to fix a stopper knot or a nut to the rope without it jamming in the pulley, you could make a stopper on the loop, the the cow would ride on a short sleeve on the rope that can slide freely but get caught on the nut. When the cow gets lifted to the top it would slide off the other side and then gets picked up again as the stopper knot comes around.